# Adding div dynamically using href link

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm trying to add a div dynamically using an  link and some javascript.  I've set up a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W4Sup/1654/.

Here's the html

```
<a href="javascript:addDiv();" onclick="addDiv();">Add Div</a>
```

Here's the css

```
div {
 border: 1px dotted red;
 padding: 10px;    
}
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

iDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the first div";

// Now create and append to iDiv
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

// The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
innerDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the inner div";

function addDiv() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'block-3';
    iDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.innerHTML = "Another inner div";
}
```

Can someone explain what I've got wrong please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/W4Sup/1655/), basically addDiv was not visible to the click event handler since it was not in a global scope (since it is inside domready event handler)

```
<script>
  var addDiv;
</script>

addDiv = function addDiv() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'block-3';
    iDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.innerHTML = "Another inner div";
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you dont need the `href`, only the `onclick` will matter, thus making it usable on any html tag, not only `<a>`'s

```
<a href="javascript:addDiv();" onclick="addDiv();">Add Div</a>
```

the `onclick` doesnt take a `;` at the end of your function, it's an assignation, you'not calling it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the assign-in-the-JS approach.  Set your event listener in your JS by grabbing that link and putting addDiv in its `click` event handler.

### [Demo using your code](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Sup/1656/)

Basic changes -

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("joe").addEventListener("click", addDiv, false);
...
function addDiv( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="joe">Add Div</a>
```

You don't have to use an ID, it was just the most convenient way in this example.  I recommend it though if that's an option for you.